# Could not find a valid gem 'mysql2-0.3.18.gem'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to Ruby on rails and i have facing this problem during Rails installation. I have searched a lot and tried many solution which were available on stackoverflow but nothing work for me. Please help how can i get out of this problem..
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had this problem before, and the reason you are getting this method, is because you are trying to download from an `https` website.

My guess is you are trying to install all the gems in your gemfile and `bundle install` didn't work. It would give you a message like

```
bundler cannot continue. Please make sure gem install samplegem succeeds
```

Change the following line in your gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

and run `bundle`

alternatively, you could do the following

```
gem install mysql2 -s http://rubygems.org
```

Either way, you should be able to install the gem.

Comment: Please mention complete description you are going very brief?

Comment: where is gem file i am trying to ask that

Comment: Where is gem file how to change from https to http?

Comment: @RanaZubair, prior to installing gems, you ought to know where the gemfile is located. In a linux installation, it's at the root level of your rails application.

Answer (score 1):

Had you already installed mysql in your machine? The same experiencing happened with me. I was using a virtual environment and trying to install gem mysql2 but I forget that I haven't mysql in my "main" environment.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following and mysql2 installed successfully.

> gem install mysql2 -s http://rubygems.org
>   But the problem remaied the same when re ran the "bundle install"
>   [image]